# Why does every path style affect also the node borders?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-path

If I add `rounded corners` to `every path/.style`, the option affects also the node borders. Why?

Is creating a style to use in a `scope` environment the correct way to avoid it? (The actual flowchart has, of course, more `\draw`s than the MWE).

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    matrix, 
    arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    basenode/.style={
        draw=gray, align=center,
        text=black, very thick,
        anchor=center,   
        align=center,
    },
    block/.style={
        basenode,  text width=7em, 
        minimum height=8ex,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    decision/.style={
        basenode,
        minimum width=12em,
        minimum height=16ex,
        diamond,  
        anchor=center,
        shape aspect=2,
        text width=5em,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    %myarrow/.style={
    every path/.style={
        gray, 
        very thick,
        rounded corners,
        -{Triangle[width=5pt]}
    },
    ]
    \matrix[
        matrix of nodes, row sep=5ex, column sep=-2em,
        ] {
     |[decision](a)| A \\
     & |[block](b)| B \\
    };
    %\begin{scope}[myarrow]
    \draw (a) -| (b);
    %\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: because the shapes are drawn by path?

Comment: @Zarko but aren't they nodes?

Comment: `\node` is `\path[node]`. You could perhaps do `every node/.append style={sharp corners}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. And if one of the node styles has rounded corners?

Comment: Why not more simply `\draw[myarrow] (a) -| (b);` without the scope?

Comment: @egreg Because I have many `\draw`s and I would like to avoid to write it for everyone.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem, try adding `rounded corners` to the `decision` or `block` style.

Comment: @CarLaTeX `\newcommand\myarrow{\draw[myarrow]}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OK, that works! If you like to draw an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @egreg I was sure there is a pure TikZ solution :)

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? https://ctan.org/pkg/flowchart

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm writing the next DuckBoat, and I would like to use a flowchart to show what you could do with TikZ. Moreover, the `flowchart` package seems a bit limited w.r.t. direct TikZ, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\node` is an abbreviation of `\path[node]`, cf. section 15.1 in the manual, so I don't think it should be a surprise.

An alternative might be to add

```
every node/.append style={sharp corners}
```

to the `tikzpicture` options. It doesn't seem like this would override a `rounded corners` in a node style.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    matrix, 
    arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    basenode/.style={
        draw=gray, align=center,
        text=black, very thick,
        anchor=center,   
        align=center,
    },
    block/.style={
        basenode,  text width=7em, 
        minimum height=8ex,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    decision/.style={
        basenode,
        minimum width=12em,
        minimum height=16ex,
        diamond, 
        anchor=center,
        shape aspect=2,
        text width=5em,
        inner sep=0pt,
    },
    %myarrow/.style={
    every path/.style={
        gray, 
        very thick,
        rounded corners,
        -{Triangle[width=5pt]}
    },
    % addition:
    every node/.append style={sharp corners}
    ]
    \matrix[
        matrix of nodes, row sep=5ex, column sep=-2em,
        ] {
     |[decision](a)| A \\
     & |[block](b)| B \\
    };
    %\begin{scope}[myarrow]
    \draw (a) -| (b);
    %\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```